# Adding controls dynamically in xaml window store app with events attached?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a canvas ,inside it an image control which has events ManipulationDelta Event , Click Event etc etc. 
I have an ADD button which add an image control to the canvas

```
Image image = new Image();
            string url = "ms-appx:///Assets/992829_484663934955807_859212711_n.jpg";
            BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();

            bm.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
            image.Source = bm;
            image.Height = 100;
            image.Width = 100;

            MyCanvas.Children.Add(image);
```

Now I want to create same events for this controls and many other also dynamically so that they have their own  ManipulationDelta and Click events . How to achieve that ? Should I use Anonymous methods,Lambda Expressions etc. Just a hint which will guide me??

Answer (score 0):

subscribe event like this

```
image.ManipulationDelta += image_ManipulationDelta;
image.Tapped += image_Tapped;


void image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}

void image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do somthing
}
```

in Visual Studio .. just type `image.ManipulationDelta +=` and then press Tab 2 times. It will create event handler method automatically

also you can create event handler by using Anonymous method

```
image.ManipulationDelta += (sender, e) =>
{
    //do something
};
```

Comment: but i dont know how many controls user will add so this is only for one suppose I add 10 images I want to drag them , rotate etc they all have their own events which I dont have right now they all are make at runime ??

Comment: if you want your image controls do the same behaviour when event trigger. just subscribe them to an event handler. In this case the event handler will do translation,rotation for each image control
. But if there is something you want to do with specific control. You can check which control trigger the event using "sender" parameter in event handler.

for example
var image = (Image)sender;

Comment: Is ther any documentation or examples  ?

Comment: same event call but from different controls ?